# Need Help! Evaluating a complicated integral

Tags: integration

For this problem, I can't seem to figure how to start. I tried to do u-substitution but it doesn't seem to work...

$$\int \frac{x^5 + 1}{x^3 -3x^2 - 10x} \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: You can break the integral up into $\int \frac{x^4}{(x-5)(x+2)}$ and $\int \frac{1}{x(x-5)(x+2)}$, then try partial fractions I guess.

Comment: Following Neptune's comment, I would **start with** [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) on $(x^4) \div (x^2 - 3x - 10).$

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^. I've edited your question to use mathjax instead of an image. This makes it so that future users can search the website if they have similar questions. In the future you should do the same so that our website is easy to use for everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

As the comments suggest, you might try the following technique:

First factor the denominator as $x^3 - 3x^2 - 10x = (x-5)(x+2)x$.

Then you should rewrite $\frac{x^5 +1}{(x-5)(x+2)x}$ using
[partial fractions](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/partialfractions.aspx):

$$x^2 + 3x + 19 + \frac{3126/5}{x-5} - \frac{31/14}{x-2} - \frac{1/10}{x}.$$

Do you see how you might evaluate the integral of the above function?

---

I hope this helps ^_^